# How can I use a dynamic route in an expo-router Link component using TypeScript?

Tags: typescript, react-native, expo, expo-router

I have a list of items that I can click to go to different pages. These items are stored in an array. They have the following shape:

```
type Item = {
  label: string
  path: ItemPath
}

type ItemPath = "/item/one" | "/item/two" | "/item/three"
```

Where `ItemPath` is a type I declared with all possible routes for each item.

Then, I'm trying to use the `Link` component as follows:

```
import { Link } from 'expo-router'

const items: Item[] = [
  {label: 'one', path: '/item/one'},
  {label: 'two', path: '/item/two'},
  {label: 'three', path: '/item/three'}
]

export default function Page() {
  // ...

  return (
    <View>
      {items.map(item => (
        <Link href={item.path} key={item.label}>
          {item.label}
        </Link>
       )}
    </View>
  )
}
```

However, the *href* attribute gives me a TypeScript error:

> Type 'ItemPath' is not assignable to type 'StaticRoutes | RelativePathString | `http${string}`'.

I've tried using `<Link href={item.path as RelativePathString} />`, but I couldn't find the type. I also spent some time looking for information, but I couldn't find anything relevant to my problem.

I was hoping TypeScript would understand my ItemPath type is a subset of all paths in the app.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved my problem using `Href<T>` in the expo-router Link component.

The code changed as follows:

```
import { Link } from 'expo-router'

const items: Item[] = [
  {label: 'one', path: '/item/one'},
  {label: 'two', path: '/item/two'},
  {label: 'three', path: '/item/three'}
]

export default function Page() {
  // ...

  return (
    <View>
      {items.map(item => (
        <Link href={item.path as Href<itemPath>} key={item.label}>
          {item.label}
        </Link>
       )}
    </View>
  )
}
```

Here is the [link to the docs](https://docs.expo.dev/router/reference/typed-routes/#statically-typed-routes)